# Push from one two-dimensional array to another two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
arr1 [
  [
    '    ', '[H] ',
    '    '
  ],
  [
    '[W] ', '[B] ',
    '    '
  ],
  [
    '[S] ', '    ',
    '[M]'
  ]
]
```

How to push the 0 indexed elements of each array in arr1 into `arr2[0]`, the 1 indexed elements of each array in arr1 into `arr2[1]` and so on, like this:

```
arr2 [
  [
    '    ', '[W] ',
    '[S] '
  ],
  [
    '[H] ', '[B] ',
    '    '
  ],
  [
    '    ', '    ',
    '[M]'
  ]
]
```

this method

```
let arr2 = []
 for (let i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++) {
   for (let j of arr1[i]) {
     arr2[i].push(j[i])
     //or arr2[i].push(j)
   }
 }
```

throws an error

```
arr2[i].push(j[i]) //or arr2[i].push(j) the same error
       ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Comment: you have to initialize the slot before accessing/pushing to it. Try adding this before the push operation `if(!arr2[i]) arr2[i] = []`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you start `arr2` as an empty array, so you need to initialize each subarray.

```js
const arr1 = [
  ['    ', '[H] ', '    '],
  ['[W] ', '[B] ', '    '],
  ['[S] ', '    ', '[M]'],
];

const arr2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (const arr of arr1) {
    if (!arr2[i]) arr2[i] = [];
    arr2[i].push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, i accidentally posted my answer [on the wrong question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709625/how-can-i-check-the-messages-that-i-received-from-whatsapp-business-api/74709794#74709794).
Here is is:

For a better understanding, you should write the array like this:

```
let arr1 = [
  ["    ", "[H] ", "    "],
  ["[W] ", "[B] ", "    "],
  ["[S] ", "    ", "[M]"]
];
```

Now you can see its a matrix you need to invert diagonally.

```
let arr2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let elements = arr1[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    let element = elements[j];
    arr2[j] = arr2[j] ?? []; //Set to empty array to prevent error
    arr2[j][i] = element;
  }
}
```