# How can I check the messages that I received from whatsapp business API?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

We are using an integration with whatsapp business API and it is working great, but we need to check if we have a new message or if the user have replied, we try it to use the whatsapp business app, but we can't access to the app and it seems like that whatsapp doesn't allow to use the App and API with the same number, then is there any way to check the messages like an app or dashboard?

I have been investigating in internet but I cannot find any solutions for that

Comment: you need to setup a webhook, read [more in detail](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks).